# Disable yum presto / deltarpms on a per-repository basis

Tags: yum

I have a local mirror of the `fedora` and `fedora-updates` repositories, but I also use other repos such as `rpmsphere` and `rpmfusion`.

For the local mirrors, my bandwidth is so fast, the deltarpms feature of yum becomes a disadvantage. So I have [disabled it](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/24911/how-i-disable-yum-presto-deltarpms-on-fedora-19/), but it seems to be a global setting.

Is there any way to configure it on a per-repository basis?